# Magento 2 Copying Template/View Files from Luma into My own Theme

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created a new Magento 2 theme and added it's parent as LUMA.

It's all working fine but I want to change the layout of my theme and the templates too.

Under Vendor ... I can see that there's all the folders and templates used in LUMA.

I work like to take a copy of all the LUMA view templates and layouts and copy them for use on my theme.

My question is ...

1. What do I copy and from where?
2. And where do I place them templates, views etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the reference for theme integration in magento 2:

http://blog.magestore.com/how-to-create-custom-theme-on-magento-2-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

To copy luma,blank theme or module templates, layout and web files to own custom theme

**1) To Copy template file:**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Follow this path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

**2) To Copy layout file:**

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Follow this path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml